# TypeError: Attempted to wrap findById which is already wrapped: Unit testing with mocha, sinon, node and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to unit test my controller method and this is what it returns when I try to stub it : `TypeError: Attempted to wrap findById which is already wrapped`. I have tried using the before and after hooks but it does not fix the issue. I am using `sinon-express-mock` for req and res and `sinon` for stubs.

```
describe('controller getUserData', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        sinon.stub(UserData, "findById");
    });
    afterEach(function() {
        UserData.findById.restore();
    });
    it('getUserData by Id', async function() {
        const mockId = sinon.stub(UserData, 'findById').returns(mockIdData[0]);
        req = mockReq();
        res = mockRes();
        next = null;
        req.params.id = mockIdData[0]._id;
        await Controller.getUserData(req, res, next);
        assert(mockId.calledWith(req.params.id));
        assert(res.status.calledWith(200));
    });
    it('should return 404 when user data is not found', async function() {
        sinon.stub(UserData, 'findById').returns(null);
        req = mockReq();
        res = mockRes();
        next = null;
        await Controller.getUserData(req, res, next);
        assert(res.status.calledWith(404));
    });
});
```

Here is my controller method:

```
exports. getUserData = async (req, res, next) => {

    const userData = await UserData.findById(req.params.id);

    if (!userData) {
        
        res.status(404).send();
    }

    res.status(200)
        .json(
            userData,
        );
};
```

Comment: Can you remove `beforeEach`? You stub the `UserData.findById` method twice in `beforeEach` hook and test case.

Comment: That works for just the findById, there are other tests in the suite that use find, findByIdAndUpdate. Not sure how that would react to the other methods

Comment: Instead of restoring the method one by one, you may want to use `sinon.restore()` in `afterEach` hook to restore all stubs

Comment: Awesome, that works. Also, using sandbox worked for me. Thanks!